# Run command on non-duplicated files

Tags: command-line, batch

I need to write a batch file which will run a command for files with .ext extension excluding "duplicated" files which have same filename but two different extensions (e.g. .ext and .txe).

I tried this but I don't know how to exclude a file with same filename as found .txe file:

```
@echo off 
forfiles /c "cmd /c if @ext==\"ext\" 
    if not @ext==\"txe\" 
     echo @fname.ext" 
pause
```

Comment: Great story, what's the question? :)  What have you got so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @techie007
I tried this but I don't know how to exclude a file with same filename as found .txe file.
'@echo off
forfiles /c "cmd /c if @ext==\"ext\" if not @ext==\"txe\" echo @fname.ext"
pause'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below will traverse the current directory looking for files matching the pattern `*.ext`. For every file found, it will execute the command `dir example.*` (the modifier `~n` strips the extension off `%%i`). The output of this dir command is piped into `findstr` to get the line indicating the number of files found. `for /F` parses this line and stores the number in `%%j`.

If 'duplicate' files with a different extension were found, this number would be greater than one. If the number is one, we're dealing with a non-duplicate and can start running commands on `%%i`. In this example, the script merely prints the filename using `echo %%i`.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.ext) do (
    for /F %%j in ('dir %%~ni.* ^| findstr /C:"File(s)"') do (
        if /I %%j EQU 1 (
            echo %%i
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: It looked complicated at first but after analysing it's clear for me. And of course it does the job perfectly. Thanks @MarcksThomas